# Cant connect to my proxied elasticsearch node

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, go, proxy

I'm having issues with connecting from my Go client to my es node.

I have elasticsearch behind an nginx proxy that sets basic auth. 
All settings are default in ES besides memory.

Via browser it works wonderfully, but not via this client: 
https://github.com/olivere/elastic

I read the docs and it says it uses the /_nodes/http api to connect. Now this is probably where I did something wrong because the response from that api looks like this:

```
{
  "_nodes" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "u6TqFjAvRBa3_4FndfKh4w" : {
      "name" : "u6TqFjA",
      "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
      "host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
      "version" : "5.6.2",
      "build_hash" : "57e20f3",
      "roles" : [
        "master",
        "data",
        "ingest"
      ],
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : [
          "[::1]:9200",
          "127.0.0.1:9200"
        ],
        "publish_address" : "127.0.0.1:9200",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm guessing I have to set the IPs to my actual IP/domain (my domain is like es01.somedomain.com)

So how do i correctly configure elastisearch so that my go client can connect?

My config files for nginx look similar to this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx

**Edit: I found a temporary solution by setting elastic.SetSniff(false) in the Options for the client, but I think that means I can't scale ES horizontally. So still looking for an alternative.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [HTTP options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html), specifically `http.publish_host` and `http.publish_port`, which should be set to the publicly reachable address and port of the Nginx server proxying the ES node.

Note that with Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9300 for the transport, you won't be able to form a cluster with nodes on other hosts. The transport can be configured similarly with the [transport options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html).